# Updating your blog from a localhost version

Tags: wordpress, localhost, dashboard

Okay, I trust this is not a [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) question, though it has something to do with server settings, the main issue might concern some programming.

I use Wordpress as my blogging platform, only problem: Using the online admin is just too slow. Uploading images, waiting for the text editor to load, even the login screen just feels a bit too long a time for me. I just want to write, *right now*.

An idea about creating a local dashboard that would update an Online version of the exact same settings came to mind. Can that sort of solution can be done? Is there a way to sync a localhost version (on my computer) of Wordpress while creating a bridge between that local version and an online one? Let all data transfer happen in the background of things, in a batch, after I'm done?

Comment: Couldn't you just move the database?

Comment: I'm thinking about a long-run: Use the localhost version as a dashboard to all blog activities. I'm trying to avoid as much ONLINE as possible.

Comment: Maybe setup a cron on your system to upload remotely? Or just a page you can visit on your localhost?

Comment: Yep. I think that would have to be it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a weblog client. See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Weblog_Client) for a list that work with Wordpress. You can also 'blog by email' but I've never used it myself.

Wordpress 2.7+ also has an offline mode using [google gears](http://gears.google.com/). On your dashboard page, there's a poorly named link called "Turbo Mode". Clicking that will install google gears and set you up for offline access.

Answer (score 0):

There was talk a while ago about an offline version of WordPress, powered by Google Gears. Not sure if it was ever implemented. You could always use something like Windows Live Writer (if you're using Windows) to write blog posts offline, and then publish them once done.